# Node.Js/Express + Angular2 image send and display image

Tags: node.js, express, angular

I'm trying to display image from Nodejs response in Angular2.

Node:

```
router.get('/users/avatar', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(req.user.avatarName, {
        root: path.join(__dirname+'/../uploads/')
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

and Angular2

```
//userService.ts
  getAvatar(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http
        .get(this.protectedUrl +'/avatar', {headers: this.protectedHeaders})
        .map(res => {
          return new Blob([res["_body"]], {
            type: 'image/png'
          })
        }).map(blob => {
            let urlCreator = window.URL;
            return  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob));
          })

  }
```

app.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
         this.userService.getAvatar().subscribe(response =>{
             console.log(response);
             this.avatarSrc=response;
         });
  }
```

app.component.htm

```
<div>
   <img [src]="avatarSrc">
<div>
```

This doesn't display anything, but wehen i check blob url, it's display "The image “blob:http://localhost:4200/2a723d0c-da55-4bd5-84fd-4895c803c7a5” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."
So what i'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Response#blob()` method to retrieve a blob:

and Angular2

```
//userService.ts
  getAvatar(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http
        .get(this.protectedUrl +'/avatar', {
            headers: this.protectedHeaders,
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
        })
        .map(res => res.blob())
        .map(blob => {
            let urlCreator = window.URL;
            return  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob));
          })

  }
```

Node:

Add a content-type on the response itself:

```
router.get('/users/avatar', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(req.user.avatarName, {
        root: path.join(__dirname+'/../uploads/'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/png'}
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok now angular return
Error: The request body isn't either a blob or an array buffer

Comment: updated the answer, it was missing responseType option